# how to update DataGrid if data goes through pipe?

Tags: wpf

I have such code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ........
    List<ConsoleData> datas = new List<ConsoleData>();
    foreach (StrategyDescriptor sd in pipeProxy.GetStrategies())
    {
        datas.Add(pipeProxy.GetData(sd.Id));
    }
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = datas;
 }
```

the problem is that dataGrid is never updated.
I would like to update it every second or so.

I'm very novice to WPF so sorry about this question - how to do that? Should I create timer or there are better technics?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ObservableCollection rather than a List if you want the UI to be aware of changes.   And the classes in your collection must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: ok I will user ObservableCollection instead of list, but who will updated ObservableCollection? I also need to add a timer that will query pipeProxy for data say every second?

Comment: Start with a timer in a loop but the problem is a timer running on the primary thread can update the UI but your UI is basically tied up.  The more elegant solution is using dispatcher and a background process.  I am not that strong with dispatcher so cannot provide specifics on how to do that.  Dispatcher is a big part of WPF but for the most part you don't need to deal with it.